# Extract subjects that meet defined criteria from time series data in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, datetime, time-series

```
RowID  SubjectID  Value      TimeStamp    
 1          1       65    2142-04-29 12:00:00 
 2          1       58    2142-04-30 03:00:00 
 3          1       55    2142-04-30 04:00:00
 4          1       54    2142-04-30 05:00:00
 5          1       69    2142-04-30 06:15:00  
 6          1       68    2142-05-01 06:45:00
 7          2       75    2142-05-04 02:00:00 
 8          2       40    2142-05-04 03:00:00
 9          2       41    2142-05-04 03:30:00 
10          2       69    2142-05-04 04:00:00
11          2       67    2142-05-04 05:00:00
```

In PostgreSQL I am trying to find subjects that have two consecutive values below 60 (there can be more than 2 below 60 but the first 2 are important to record)followed by two consecutive values above 60 that occur afterwards. I'm also interested in the length of time between these 2 events. I hope to get an output such as:

```
 SubjectID  DidEventOccur Duration 
 1          1             03:15:00
 2          1             01:00:00
```

The duration is the time the first value below 60 occurred to the time the second value above 60 occurred. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and `lead()` to identify the rows and get the information you need:

```
select t.subjectId, t.didEventOccur,
       (next_timestamp - timestamp) as duration
from (select t.*,
             lag(t.value) over (partition by t.subjectid order by t.timestamp) as prev_value,
             lead(t.value) over (partition by t.subjectid order by t.timestamp) as next_value,
             lead(t.timestamp) over (partition by t.subjectid order by t.timestamp) as next_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where value < 60 and next_value < 60 and
      (prev_value is null or prev_value >= 60);
```